# Is this a known property of cofactors?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples

There is a line I don't understand in a proof I'm reading. It goes like this:

Let $A_{ki}$ be the cofactor of $a_{ki}$. Then:

$$\sum_{i} A_{ij} \sum_{k} a_{ki}h_{k} = \sum_{k} h_{k} \sum_{i} A_{ij}a_{ki} = \Delta \cdot h_{j}$$

where $\Delta$ is the deteminant of the (symmetric) matrix whose entries are the $a_{ki}$.

Can any of you tell if the second equality is valid at all? I know that the $j$-th summand of the outer sum is equal to $\Delta \cdot h_{j}$ but, in the absence of additional information on the $h_{k}$'s, may we really conclude that $\sum_{k} h_{k} \sum_{i} A_{ij}a_{ki} =\Delta \cdot h_{j}$?

Thanks in advance for your reading suggestions, replies, etc.

Comment: I use computer to check the last equality for the $3 \times 3$ (symmetric) case and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the formula
[$$\operatorname{adj} A \cdot A = \det A \cdot I$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Inverses)
We have
$$\sum_k A_{ki} a_{kj} =
\begin{cases}
\det A &\text{ if } i = j \\
0 &\text{ if } i \ne j
\end{cases}$$
since $\operatorname{adj} A = (A_{ji})_{ij}$ (the index are reversed!)

After relabeling the index $(k \mapsto i, i \mapsto j, j \mapsto k)$
$$\sum_i A_{ij} a_{ik} =
\begin{cases}
\det A &\text{ if } j = k \\
0 &\text{ if } j \ne k
\end{cases}$$
By the assumption that $A$ is symmetric, i.e. $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$
$$\sum_i A_{ij} a_{ki} =
\begin{cases}
\det A &\text{ if } j = k \\
0 &\text{ if } j \ne k
\end{cases}$$
So our big sum $$\sum_k h_k \sum_i A_{ij} a_{ki} = \det A \cdot h_j$$
as all the $k \ne j$ terms die.

**Credits: This proof comes to my mind after reading page 20 of http://www.math.ku.edu/~slshao/fall2013math290lecture11.pdf**

Comment: Thanks a bunch, @Alex Vong!

Comment: You're welcomed!